# How do I solve a system of linear inequalities

Tags: inequality

I have the following equations:

First equation: $(r_{1} + r_{2})K_{m} - C > (r_{1} -r_{2})K_{M} + C$

Second equation: $(r_{1} - r_{2})K_{m} > C$

With $K_{m},K_{M},C>0$

I want to find the ranges of solutions for $r_{1}$ and $r_{2}$ in terms of $K_{m},K_{M},C$. But I am not sure how to approach this because these are inequalities.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming?